# typescript complier and tsconfig.json set up question

Tags: typescript

Hey guys I'm trying to compile tsc but project is not compiling.
Here's my `tsconfig.json` file.

```html
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", //s
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node",
      "@types/jest"
    ], //s
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es5",
      "es2015"
    ], //s
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node", //s
    "resolveJsonModule": true, //s
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react", //s
    "noImplicitAny": false, //s
    "sourceMap": true, //s
    "outDir": "dist/build/src", //s
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/tests/**/*@(*.ts|*.tsx|*.js)"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I am running tsc but nothing is happening.

Can you guys help me out to fix this ?

Thank you!

Comment: So to clarify, there is no errors and the dist/build/src folder is empty after running tsc?

Comment: You have configured `noEmit` to `true`, so there will be no compilation output. And if there are no compiler errors (type problems) in your source, there will also be nothing printed to `stdout`. What are your expectations?